# Is it possible to add a google account to "Accounts & Sync" Without launching a login screen

Tags: android, accountmanager, securityexception

I have tried many different approaches to solving this issue, that seems us solvable.
I've implemented a C2DM messaging system with Apps engine (same as JumpNote example) and I want the Android Device to automatically create a specified google account without asking for credentials. I've used the following method:

```
    AccountManager accMgr = AccountManager.get(this);
    final Account account = new Account(this.getString(R.string.push_account), "com.google");
    accMgr.addAccountExplicitly(account, this.getString(R.string.push_account_pass), null);
```

This throws the following:
**java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10086 is different than the authenticator's uid**

Does anyone ever succeded creating a google account without asking the user to manualy type credentials?

Thanks to anyone that shed some light on this.

Comment: I am also trying to do this, and I understand why we receive this exception...but did you find any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly not what you want to do.

Doing it the way that you are creates a massive security vulnerability, as anyone can unzip and decompile your APK and acquire the username and password you're using.

Now they have access to any phone running your app - installing things from the web market seems like the most blatant risk.

Comment: Thanks Charles, you right Its too risky. this issue forces me to modify the server side because i'm using C2DM to receive push msgs, I have an example of JumpNote and It works nicely only in one account. I need to change it to msg multiple different accounts now. Does anyone implemented it? Should I store this data in the server? I really have to re think it

Comment: @Li3ro if you please post the solution for one account, thanks in advance!!

Comment: @MR Mido , solution for one account (if fits your needs) exsists here : http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/source/checkout
The JumpNotes example project contains the Android and Server side code. If its not what you meant, Please elaborate
Y